# ¿Cómo borrar registros viejos según la fecha?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy trabajando con unas tablas en `mysql` y no estoy pudiendo borrar los registros más antiguos con respecto a las fechas, hay varios usuarios que tienen varios registros pero **solo quiero dejar los registros más recientes de cada usuario**.

```
select min(updated_at) as olds
from vital_signs  group by id order by patient_id
```

Este sería mi query en SQL que me trae todos los registro que quiero borrar, pero al agregar el delete me sale un error.

Comment: tal vez deberías usar una subconsulta dentro de la consulta delete

Comment: si hago una consulta usando el updated_at igual me da error, porque la consulta que hago saca una lista de los registros que quiero borrar

Comment: ¿Como haces el delete?

Comment: `delete from vital_signs where updated_at > (select min(updated_at) as olds
from vital_signs  group by id order by patient_id)`  asi lo puse, pero da error 1093

Comment: Vale, creo que no te funciona porque no puedes borrar de una tabla sobre la que estas haciendo un select.

Comment: Probaste con algo asi? __DELETE FROM vital_signs  WHERE id IN ( select id, min(updated_at) as olds
from vital_signs  group by id HAVING olds < fechaAeliminar )__

Comment: Probablemente esto te pueda servir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562787/how-to-delete-from-select-in-mysql

Comment: @JDev igual sigue saliendo error

Comment: Prueba de esta forma, sugerida y ampliamente aceptada [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12969601/5587982): **`DELETE t.*
FROM vital_signs t
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
             FROM (SELECT id, min(updated_at) as olds
      FROM vital_signs  
      GROUP BY id 
      ORDER BY patient_id) x);`** no sé si realmente el `ORDER BY patient_id` sea necesario  ¿? . Como precaución, siempre haz las pruebas sobre una copia de la tabla, no sea que borres datos de forma errónea.

Comment: @A.Cedano el `order by` patient_id es para saber si la consulta me tira los resultados que quiero nada mas. y sobre el SQL que me pusiste sale este error `Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnec.`

Comment: Tratemos de satisfacer ese requerimiento otorgando un `WHERE` a la consulta: **`DELETE FROM vital_signs WHERE id IN (
  SELECT tmp.id FROM (
    SELECT id, min(updated_at) as olds FROM vital_signs GROUP BY id ORDER BY patient_id
  ) tmp
);`**

Comment: Eso me permite eliminar por fin los registros pero me trae todos los registros y los elimina todo, es decir mi tabla se queda vacia

Comment: Entonces no es como decías en la pregunta, que esa consulta te traía los registros que querías eliminar. Algo que puedes hacer es ponerle un límite a la subconsulta, pe: `LIMIT 5` si quieres que te elimine solo 5 registros.

Comment: Hola,¿si el id existe una sola vez en la tabla lo tienes que eliminar?,ó ¿Solamente vas a eliminar los que tienen mas de un registro y dejaras el mas nuevo de ellos?.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque el método que ha probado [@JCVN08](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95538/jcvn08) funciona cuando los datos están correctamente ordenados en la base de datos, deja de funcionar pasado un tiempo.

Puede comprobarse este problema en [este ejemplo en línea (pulsa para ver)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7raPLc6yqD1o8J3juF84gs/0).

La primera solución que propongo no es la óptima (ver el segundo ejemplo), pero hace su trabajo correctamente independientemente del orden de los registros en la base de datos:

```
DELETE FROM vital_signs
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT
    vs.id
  FROM (
    SELECT
      patient_id,
      MAX(updated_at) updated_at
    FROM vital_signs
    GROUP BY patient_id
    ORDER BY patient_id
  ) x
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM vital_signs
    ) vs
  ON x.updated_at = vs.updated_at
    AND x.patient_id = vs.patient_id
);
```

En una consulta anidada consigo todas las duplas `patient_id`/`MAX(updated_at)` para posteriormente obtener el `id` de los registros que contienen dicha dupla (si no son clave única se debería usar un `LIMIT 1`).

Puede comprobarse el correcto funcionamiento de este método en [este ejemplo en línea (pulsa para ver)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7raPLc6yqD1o8J3juF84gs/1).

Una solución mejorada basada en tablas temporales puede ser la siguiente:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE vital_signs_ids
SELECT
  id
FROM vital_signs vs
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    patient_id,
    MAX(updated_at) updated_at
  FROM vital_signs
  GROUP BY patient_id
  ) vs_max
WHERE
  vs_max.patient_id = vs.patient_id
  AND vs_max.updated_at = vs.updated_at;

DELETE FROM vital_signs
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM vital_signs_ids
);
```

Igual que en la consulta anterior, metemos en una tabla temporal (que existe únicamente para la conexión en curso y sólo durante el tiempo que dure la conexión) los `id` de aquellos registros que coincidan con la dupla `patient_id`/`MAX(updated_at)`.

La ventaja de esta consulta es que no se realiza un escaneo completo de la tabla (`SELECT * FROM vital_signs`) como en la consulta anterior, mejorando enormemente el rendimiento en tablas con grandes cantidades de datos.

Puede comprobarse el correcto funcionamiento de este método mejorado en [este ejemplo en línea (pulsa para ver)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7raPLc6yqD1o8J3juF84gs/2).

Answer (score 1):

## Buenas a todos.

Al final pude resolver mi problema la solucion fue por otro lado pero les comparto, primero hice un `select` para sacar todos los ultimos registros de cada usuario y luego use otro select para sacar el id de ese `select`, posteriormente use el correspondiente `delete` para borrar lo que no necesitaba

`delete from vital_signs where id not in(select x.ide from
(select max(id) as ide,patient_id,max(updated_at) as olds from vital_signs group by patient_id order by patient_id) as x)`

Comment: Ten cuidado porque en un `GROUP BY` al que haces un `MAX(updated_at)`, el campo `patient_id` no tiene por qué ser el que contiene el valor máximo. Probablemente esto no ocurra si los campos se obtienen ordenados por fecha, pero pasado un tiempo es posible que no lo estén.

Comment: He reproducido el problema con el que te puedes encontrar en [este ejemplo en línea (pulsa para ver)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7raPLc6yqD1o8J3juF84gs/0).